# Ajax XMLHttpRequest.Upload returning null and "progress" eventListener not working even though the file has been uploaded

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

To learn more JavaScript and PHP, I am currently working on a small private project that allows me to upload single or multiple files to my server via PHP. The file/s get sent to the PHP script via Ajax. If I upload several files, I send one file after the other in a loop via Ajax to the PHP script. Since I wanted to make the visual part of the upload a bit more appealing, I added a progress bar via xhr.upload and a "progress" eventlistener, which worked well until a while ago.

However, after uploading a file for the first time in a while, I noticed that the progress bar no longer works. In the meantime, the code around the function has of course been extended, but the function itself has remained the same. Furthermore, uploading the file(s) to the server works perfectly and I get no errors.

After a few console outputs, it quickly became clear that the xhr.upload function only returns "null" values (see screenshot below). I guess that the "progress" eventlistener not firing is also due to this?

[image: Console output of XMLHttpRequest after upload]

Im working with php 8.0.8 and i am using MAMP as my localhost.
I tested in Chrome and Safari.

My HTML part:

```
<form method="post" id="dropBoxForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false">
 <div class="drop-zone" id="drop-zone">
  <span class="drop-zone__prompt">Dateien hier ablegen oder klicken</span>
  <input id="dropboxFile" type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" class="drop-zone__input checkSize" require>
 </div>
</form>
```

This is my JavaScript function with which I send the files via Ajax to my upload.php:

```
const text = document.getElementById("usrMessage");

let sizeName = ' Kb';
let fileListArr = [];
let files = [];
let sumFileSize = 0;
let id = [];

// Check Uploadbutton File
$('#drop-zone').find('.checkSize').each(function () {
    $(this).bind('change', function () {
        copyFileArray(this.files);
        checkFile();
        uploadFiles();
    });
});

// Check Drag and Drop file
document.querySelectorAll(".drop-zone__input").forEach((inputElement) => {
    const dropZoneElement = inputElement.closest(".drop-zone");
    dropZoneElement.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        copyFileArray(inputElement.files);
        checkFile();
        uploadFiles();
    });
});

// Copy all files from the input into a new array so that the array can be modified e.g. remove array element
function copyFileArray(file) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(fileListArr, file);
    //console.log(fileListArr);
}

// Function with which the names and file sizes are output 
function checkFile() {
    id = [];
    let files = fileListArr;
    sumFileSize = 0;
    $('#dateienZumUploaden').html('');
    for (let i = 0, l = files.length; i < l; i++) {
        id[i] = Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);
        console.log('i= ' + i);
        let filesName = files[i].name;
        let filesSize = files[i].size;
        sumFileSize += files[i].size;
        $('#dateienZumUploaden').append('<div class="entrieWrap entrieWrapUploadform"><div class="entrieFile">' + filesName + '</div><div class="entrieInfo">' + roundFileSize(filesSize) + sizeName + '</div><br/><div class="progress-wrp"><div class="progressbar progressbar_' + id[i] + '"></div></div></div>');
    }

    if (files.length >= 1) {
        $('#uploadBereit').css({ 'display': 'block' });
        // Kb zu Mb wenn Wert größer als 1 Mb
        $('#sumGroesse').html('Alle Dateien: ' + roundFileSize(sumFileSize) + sizeName + '<br/>');
    } else {
        resetForm();
    }

    if (sumFileSize > 134217728) {
        $('#sumGroesse').append('Datei ist zu groß.');
    } else {
        $('#sumGroesse').append('');
    }
}


let percentComplete = [];
let xhr = [];
let j = 0;

// Ajax Function with which the data is uploaded
function uploadFiles() {
    text.innerHTML = "Sendet ...";
    
    $("#mssgBox").css({ 'display': 'block', 'bottom': '0' });

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file[]', fileListArr[j]);
    let progressbarID = $(".progressbar_" + id[j]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "../upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        xhr: function () {
            xhr[j] = new XMLHttpRequest();
            console.log(xhr[j]);
            xhr[j].upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
                console.log(e.loaded + ' & ' + e.total + ' & ' + Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total) * 100));
                progressbarID.css({ "width": Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total) * 100) + '%' });
                //notifyMe('Uploading', Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total) * 100));
            }, false);
            return xhr[j];
        },
        error: function (error) {
            text.innerHTML += '<br/>Error: ' + error;
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        timeout: 60000
    }).done(function (respond) {
        text.textContent = '';
        text.innerHTML += respond + '<br/>';
        console.log(respond);
        notifyMe(respond, '100');

        j = j + 1;
        if (j < fileListArr.length) {
            uploadFiles();
        } else {
            j = 0;
        }

        $("#uploadedFiles").load("filesuploaded.php");
    });
}
```

My upload.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('assets/imgResize.php');
$total_count = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

$phpFileUploadErrors = array(
  0 => 'ACHTUNG: There is no error, the file uploaded with success',
  1 => 'ACHTUNG: The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini',
  2 => 'ACHTUNG: The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form',
  3 => 'ACHTUNG: The uploaded file was only partially uploaded',
  4 => 'ACHTUNG: No file was uploaded',
  6 => 'ACHTUNG: Missing a temporary folder',
  7 => 'ACHTUNG: Failed to write file to disk.',
  8 => 'ACHTUNG: A PHP extension stopped the file upload.',
);

for ($i = 0; $i < $total_count; $i++) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"][$i] > 0) {
    $errorCode = $_FILES["file"]["error"][$i];
    echo $phpFileUploadErrors[$errorCode];
  } else {
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_SESSION['userUid'] . '/' . str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]))) {

      echo "ACHTUNG: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] . " existiert bereits.<br/>";

    } else {

      if (imageType($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'][$i])) {
        $image = scaleImageFileToBlob($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], 'thumb_' . $_SESSION['userUid'] . '_' . str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]));
        if ($image == '') {
          echo 'ACHTUNG: Image type not supported';
        }

      }

      $uploadFile = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i], "upload/" . $_SESSION['userUid'] . '/' . str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]));
      if ($uploadFile) {
        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] . " erfolgreich hochgeladen";
      } else {
        echo "ACHTUNG: Fehler beim hochgeladen von " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Can someone tell me for what reason I only get null values for my xhr.upload?

Also if you need more information, I will give them to you.

Thanks in advance :)

P.S. I can imagine that doing multiple ajax requests in a loop like I did is probably not optimal but it's the only way I managed to get one progressbar per uploaded file.

Comment: Unless you explicitly set the various event listeners of a XHR object, I wouldn't worry that those properties are null.  It looks like the first request worked (you got a response).  This might be a red herring.

Comment: @James Thanks for the answer and the edit. So if I understand you correctly, the error is probably elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you set `processData: false` to `processData: true`, inside your Ajax code?

Comment: I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation at i (jquery.min.js:2:73525)

Comment: Could you add your html code as well? Well, when I try to test it, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: I have edited the content of my question and added HTML. In addition to this I have extended the JavaScript part

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my problem wasn't so much the returned null values of the xhr.upload (as  @James said) but that **it had to do with the Service Workers**. Sorry, I didn't mention them in my question as I didn't suspect they could have an impact.

Anyway, I've found a solution to my problem here: [AJAX (XMLHttpRequest) progress monitoring doesn't work with Service Workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54448367/ajax-xmlhttprequest-progress-monitoring-doesnt-work-with-service-workers)